# How to crunch down Pandas rows into one, aplying different conditions to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following

[image: table]

I need to figure out how to get something like the following out of it.

[image: output]

By adding grouping by both NAME and DATE, getting the total FT but saving the first ORI and last END.
I have been trying using variarions of groupby with aggregations to no avail.

```
df.groupby(["NAME"]).agg(sum)
```

Any help would be apreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby.agg`

```
(df.groupby(['NAME','DATE'])
   .agg({'ORI':'first', 'END':'last', 
         'TO':'first', 'LAND':'last', 'FT':'sum'})
)
```